# How to avoid multiple slashes after domain name in url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link `http://mysite.com/myname` which shows the profile page.. But if i use multiple

slashes like `http://mysite.com///myname` , it also shows the page..

My htaccess code is :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ profile.php?username=%1 [L,QSA]
```

How to avoid this problem?

Can someone help me?

Comment: There is/are some bad rewrites in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: My htaccess code is :    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile.php?username=%1 [L,QSA].. anything wrong?

Comment: @David : Ma problem is http://mysite.com///myname , it shows profile page even it has more than one slash after domain.... But i dont want to show profile page in this situation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why do you really want to block multiple slashes but here is a way to do that:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

This will give Forbidden error is a URI has multiple slashes at start like `///myname` will generate:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /myname on this server.

Comment: Hmm I posted that after properly testing it. Can you post your full .htaccess in your question (not in comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following if you want to ensure you're not treating multiple forward slashes as a single slash (which seems to be default Apache behavior and not any sort of bug or the result of a bad rewrite).

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[^/\s]+\ HTTP
```

This should enforce a single-slash rule. Of course, this will also make it impossible to use anything like `http://example.com/myname/edit`, but that could be worked around using a more complicated regex if necessary.

Comment: You should add this **before** your other RewriteConds. If doing that doesn't work, I'm out of explanations since either @anubhava's answer or my answer should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove double slashes from the urls.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^ $0 [R=302]
```

Change the 302 to 301 once you get it working.