# why two slashes in this web directory

Tags: url, google-search-console

Google stopped crawling my webpage because my `robots.txt` file was inadvertently moved. It said I should try making sure it is there by going to the address: `http://www.site.com//robots.txt`. It had two slashes just like that. But it still works. It also works with three. What's up with that? Even if I can sort of see why it could be ignored—I'm not specifying any directory between the two—why would it be preferential to display a url like this, as the google webmasters' page does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most (all?) servers seem to allow several slashes directly after the hostname (not in other positions, though), see for example:

- http://www.google.com//////////robots.txt
- https://stackoverflow.com/////robots.txt
- http://en.wikipedia.org////////////////////////robots.txt

(Related question: [How to avoid multiple slashes after domain name in url using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9188350/1591669))

However, when Google Webmaster Tools displays the URL with two slashes, you probably have set your domain in the GWT preferences with a trailing slash (`http://example.com/` instead of `http://example.com`). See [this question for Google Analytics](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35341/24166) (I guess it should be similar for GWT).

Comment: This is some nice deduction and a great answer. Thanks so much!